# Fetching data from multiple Oracle databases as a single resultset using PHP oci8 with pagination

Tags: php, oracle, oci8

1. I have 5 different Oracle databases viz FDB1617, FDB1516,FDB1415,
   FDB1413 and FDB1312.
2. Their database structures are all the same.
3. I would like to get data from all the databases in a single query
   using PHP and OCI8 with pagination.

For eg:

```
SELECT ID,ContactName, Phone FROM FDB1617
```

should fetch data from all the 5 databases;

The following code can be used for pagination

```
    public function execFetchPage($sql, $action, $firstrow = 1, $numrows = 1, $bindvars = array()) {
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT a.*, ROWNUM AS rnum FROM (' . $sql . ') a WHERE ROWNUM <= :sq_last) WHERE :sq_first <= RNUM';
        array_push($bindvars, array(':sq_first', $firstrow, -1));
        array_push($bindvars, array(':sq_last', $firstrow + $numrows - 1, -1));
        $res = $this->execFetchAll($query, $action, $bindvars);
        return($res);
    }
```

Please help and thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you have 5 identical databases?

Comment: Individual database for each financial year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [database links](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_admin002.htm#ADMIN12150) and `UNION` to issue multiple queries while returning a single resultset.

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK link_name CONNECT TO username IDENTIFIED BY password USING connection_string;
...
```

And then:

```
SELECT ID, ContactName, Phone FROM table_name
UNION
SELECT ID, ContactName, Phone FROM table_name@link_name
UNION
...
```